# How to avoid undefined method error for Nilclass

Tags: ruby

I use the dbf gem to read data out of an df file. I wrote some code:

```
    # encoding: UTF-8
    require 'dbf'
    widgets = DBF::Table.new("patient.dbf")
      widgets.each do |record|
       puts record.vorname
      end
```

Basically the code works but after ruby writes about 400 `record.vorname` to the console i get this error:

```
  ...
  Gisela
  G?nter
  mycode.rb:5:in `block in <main>': undefined method `vorname' for nil:NilClass (NoM
  ethodError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbf-2.0.6/lib/
    dbf/table.rb:101:in `block in each'
    ......
```

My question is how can i avoid this error? Therefore it would be intresting why ( how you can see in the error) the `record.vorname`'s with ä,ö,ü are displayed like ?,?,? for eg:

`Günter` is transformed to `G?nter`

Thanks

Comment: That means that there are `nil` elements in your `widgets` array. Maybe there's something about DBF.

Comment: Now i wrote puts record.vorname unless record.vorname == nil but get the same error!

Comment: `record` is nil, not its `vorname`

Comment: Thanks, now it works! Can you please post it as answer? And do you have any clue why ö,ü,ä are displayed as ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your question about the wrong chars, according to the dfb documentation:

> Encodings (Code Pages)
>
> dBase supports encoding non-english characters in different formats.
>   Unfortunately, the format used is not always set, so you may have to
>   specify it manually. For example, you have a DBF file from Russia and
>   you are getting bad data. Try using the 'Russion OEM' encoding:
>
> table = DBF::Table.new('dbf/books.dbf', nil, 'cp866')
>
> See [doc/supported_encodings.csv](https://github.com/infused/dbf/blob/master/docs/supported_encodings.csv) for a full list of supported
>   encodings.

So make sure you use the right encoding to read from the DB.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, your DBF driver returns `nil` records. You can pretend that this problem doesn't exist by skipping those.

```
widgets.each do |record|
  puts record.vorname if record
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the NoMethodError for nil:Nil Class you can probably try this:

```
require 'dbf'
widgets = DBF::Table.new("patient.dbf")
  widgets.each do |record|
   puts record.vorname unless record.blank?
  end
```